# Authenticated React Routes redirect to /

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, use-effect

I have a react routing problem I cannot figure out. I have authenticated routes to everything except my login page. The authentication is working correctly and I can navigate around the page when clicking buttons and links but when I type in the route directly to the URL I am redirected to localhost:3000/ . I know why this is happening I just cannot think of a fix for it. Below is all related code. The main problem is the useEffect hook in the login component redirecting to / .

When I type in the url something like localhost:3000/user I am sent to localhost:3000/

What can I do instead?

PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isAuthenticated } = authContext;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to='/login' /> : <Component {...props} />
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Login.js

```
const Login = props => {
    useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      props.history.push('/');
    }
    }, [error, onLoad, isAuthenticated, props.history]);

    useEffect(() => {
      onLoad();
    }, [error, onLoad, isAuthenticated, props.history]);
}
```

Comment: I think this could happen if you're using a token or something so when you're not refreshing everything is fine but when you're trying to add the URL directly you're refreshing the page so anything that you've stored in the client-side will not persist.

Comment: Yeah , that makes sense. I am using AWS Cognito and getting a session , just still learning how to actually make use of it. Ill look into that , thanks @MajidEltayeb